# What is the point of switching to ProgPOW for ethereum, when POS is coming in the coming year(s)?

Tags: mining, proof-of-stake, hardforks, asics, progpow

With the recent discussion of the new ProgPOW mining switch. What is the point of it when POS is coming in the coming year(s)? I understand it disables the ASIC miners, while benefiting the GPU miners. But this wouldn't this cause chaos for Ethereum causing a fork of Ethereum again with ASIC miners staking on the old algo while the new GPU miners go on the new Ethereum chain? I don't understand the cost/benefits of doing something so drastic when POS is supposedly coming in the coming year(s)?

Comment: to avoid potential 51% attack by ASICs